# Trouble getting the Blog page to show up correctly

Tags: links, blog-page

I'm having a completely new problem and can't figure it out so I'm hoping someone can help me.

The website is http://www.talkingdogtemplates.com. It's a big site that uses WordPress as a CMS primarily, and I have the blog page set to http://www.talkingdogtemplates.com/blog.html. I'm using the .html on PAGES plugin to get the extension and I've never had this problem in the past with over 50 WordPress CMS/blogs. (not even sure that's the cause, probably not)

So the problem is that the post DOES show up on the blog page but the link in the header does not link and none of the author and date info shows up. It's like each time I edit the index.php document and reload it it's just being ignored. So weird.

Here's the main piece of the index.php doc:

```
<div id="main_content">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', ''), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <small><?php the_time(__('F jS, Y', '')) ?> by <?php the_author() ?></small>

                <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content(__('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;', '')); ?>
                </div>

                <p class="postmetadata"><?php the_tags(__('Tags:', '') . ' ', ', ', '<br />'); ?> <?php printf(__('Posted in %s', ''), get_the_category_list(', ')); ?> | <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', ''), '', ' | '); ?>  <?php comments_popup_link(__('No Comments &#187;', ''), __('1 Comment &#187;', ''), __('% Comments &#187;', ''), '', __('Comments Closed', '') ); ?></p>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'm really hoping someone can help me. I've tried everything I can think of so I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes can solve this easily. Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Are you *sure* this is the code for the content it's pulling in?  Because the code you show says the title should be an h2 tag with a link, but if you vire the source code, the title is an h1 tag with no link.

What I do is check for the template first - type in the template file name just before the get_header() call in the template file, and see what template is actually being pulled in there - because I think it's pulling in a template other than what you think it is.

Comment: I know. I'm sure it's pulling in that template. There is only 1 template installed on the system. I think it's pulling the page.php for some reason even though the blog is set to appear on that page. It's really strange.

Comment: just to make sure: a template is a file within a theme; please check your theme files, and see if the theme contains a home.php or front-page.php, for instance. what you posted is definitevely not the tempalte that creates the content of your linked web page.

Comment: That's how WordPress works.  If you have a page.php template file, and your blog is set to use some Page to display your posts on, then it'll use the page.php template file.  If you don't want it to, then in your settings, set the front page to show the most recent posts.  Then it'll use the index.php file.  To make the layout different, you can use conditional statements.